# How to specify Reply-To using send_raw_email in boto3?

Tags: python, boto3, amazon-ses

Using boto3's  [`send_email`](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/ses.html#SES.Client.send_email) I can easily set up custom reply-to addresses with `ReplyToAddresses`. But how do I achieve the same behaviour with [`send_raw_email`](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/ses.html#SES.Client.send_raw_email)?

Simple `send_email` example:

```py
import boto3

client = boto3.client('ses')

client.send_email(**{
    'Source': "john@smith.com",
    'Destination': {
        'ToAddresses': ["friend.of.johns@smith.com"],
    },
    'Message': {
        'Subject': {'Data': "Hello!"},
        'Body': {
            'Text': {'Data': "How are you?"},
        },
    },
    'ReplyToAddresses': ['another.john@smith.com']
})
```

What would this look like with `send_raw_email` (in particular `ReplyToAddresses`)?

Comment: What is your code so far? Show what you are passing to the `RawMessage` parameter.

Comment: @Tomalak I've update the question with a `send_email` sample. I know how to do a basic send with `send_raw_email`, but I haven't been able to achieve a custom reply-to address.

The reason I'm asking is I need to be able to set some custom headers and hence use `send_raw_email`.

Comment: I understood that from your question. But the `send_email()` example isn't what you're going for, right? Can you show that basic `send_raw_email` you currently have?

Answer (score 2):

The [`send_raw_email` API](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/ses.html#SES.Client.send_raw_email) requires you to pass in a complete RFC5322 message as a `bytes` object.  Ad-libbing from your example, something like

```py
from email.message import EmailMessage
import boto3

client = boto3.client('ses')

msg = EmailMessage()
msg['from'] = "john@smith.com"
msg['to'] = "friend.of.johns@smith.com"
msg['subject'] = "Hello!"
msg['reply-to'] = "another.john@smith.com"
msg.set_content("How are you?")

response = client.send_raw_email(
    RawMessage={
        'Data': msg.as_string().encode('us-ascii')
    },
    FromArn='string',
    # ... etc etc
)
```

The `.encode()` is required to force the `as_string()` string into a `bytes` object.  You will want to make sure you only use 7-bit ASCII in the message (for other SES reasons, too), otherwise you will get a `UnicodeEncodeError`.  The Python MIME libraries generally take care of this for you, though you have to use slightly more complex code than the above if you need non-ASCII strings in the email headers.

Answer (score 0):

You can just add it to the Message, something like this one:

```
{ 'Message' : 'reply-to': {'Data': "email-id"} }
```

P.S: Follow [RFC 5322](https://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc5322.txt) to construct the message.